# Gerar automação de uma função

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho 5 tabelas:

```
pastores,
redes,
regioes,
areas,
setores,
celulas
```

Nessa ordem,

Todas as 5 tem esses **2** campos em comum, um de identificação e outro que é o nome.

```
idPastores, idRedes, ....
nome
```

Tenho esse **script jQuery** abaixo para popular um `select` de

```
redes por pastor
regioes por redes,
etc...
```

Gostaria de montar uma função que me permitisse fazer apenas um script para todos eles.

**JQuery**

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#idPastor").on("change", function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/buscarDados.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                  idPastor: $("#idPastor").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','block');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','none');

                $("#idRede").empty();

                if (result[0] == ""){
                    $("#idRede").append("<option value=>Sem Redes</option>");
                } else {
                    result.forEach(function(option){
                        $("#idRede").append("<option value=" + option["idRede"] + ">" + option["nome"] + "</option>")
                    });
                }
            }

        });


    });

});
```

**PHP**:

```
require_once "../../../config.php";

$redes = $redesDao->pesquisaRedesParametro("idPastor", $_POST["idPastor"]);

$options = null;
$i = 0;

if ($redes == null) $options [0] = "";
else {
         foreach ($redes as $rede):

            $options[$i]["idRede"] = $rede->getIdRede();
            $options[$i]["nome"]   = $rede->getNome();
            $i++;

         endforeach;

}

echo json_encode($options);
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a montar essa função que evitaria fazer 5 vezes o mesmo script?

Comment: obrigado pelo edição LipESprY -de folga-